# How to develop tabs in angular7 which switch among two different components?

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material, angular7, angular-ui-tabset

I have generated three different components in angular 7 project

```
ng g c mycomp1
ng g c mycomp2
ng g c mycomp3
```

now I want to develop a tab in `mycop1` component which looks like below

[image: Tabs image]

by clicking on First tab it should display HTML or render the content from the same component. 
by clicking on the Second tab I required to render content from mycomp2 component(from the different component), 
Similarly from the third tab required to render from mycomp3 component.
kindly help how can I proceed to do this,  
Thanks

Comment: Tabs should be router links and bellow should be a router outlet. You can learn all of that if you finish the Angular tutorial. https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: You can go through the following articles -

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html

https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/learning-ng2-creating-tab-component/

I have recently implemented tabs in my application by following these articles.

Comment: HI @user2216584, view wise your example looks ok but I want to render the content from another component by using routing. can you help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let assume we have 4 components (app.component, a.component, b.component, c.component)

check the complete code in the below url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gerrxm

Comment: i dont want to use like  <app-mycomp1></app-mycomp1> instead i want to use routing to display content

Comment: Now check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gerrxm, i have updated the code by using router outlet, this might help you to solve your problem.

Comment: If you feel this is right answer mark it, so others can use this.

Comment: I am implementing logic on one  of the newly created component, for example, mycomp1  not in appcomponent.html , what if I need to show the content from the same HTML after clicking on  Tab1.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that you will need to keep these tabs at the top level of an application at all times. if you wanted the tabs to sit inside of a page you already have that is within the router outlet you would need a router outlet within a router outlet.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a container that hold all 3 components and add `ngIf` to each and every component that will decide whether to show it or not.

And of course, you always can use Angular Material Tabs:
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Comment: No. Use routing and router-outlet. This is just bad practice.

Comment: @ritaj - What is bad practice?

Comment: What you wrote. Don't use 3 `ngIf`s if you can use router-outlet which is built literally for this situation.

Comment: And what if I don't want my tabs to be changed or control by route?

Comment: Why would you not want that?

Comment: Who said that every time I'm clicking on a tab I need to change the route?

Comment: Then at least use a `ngSwitch`, either way `ngIf` is a terrible solution.

Comment: LOL!!
I advised for ngIf just to draw a general idea. If you have more than a few tabs. yes, sure - use ngSwitch. that's really won't make the big difference

Comment: I agree with this approach.  You will not need to have a router-outlet within a router-outlet.  by just doing the if statement you can move quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Angular Material but you'll need to use the router to navigate to each.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },

    { path: 'mycomp1', component: MyComp1Component },
    { path: 'mycomp2', component: MyComp2Component },
    { path: 'mycomp3', component: MyComp3Component }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Html file  :

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" routerLink="/tab1">Tab 1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" routerLink="/tab2">Tab 2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" routerLink="/tab3">Tab 3</button>
</div>

Using router method in component
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="setTab('tab1')">Tab 1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="setTab('tab2')">Tab 2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" (click)="setTab('tab3')">Tab 3</button>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}
  setTab(tabname: string) {
    this.router.navigate([`/${tabname}`]);
  }

}
```

CSS :

```
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```